# How are seeds, profiles, accounts and address balances handled in the new UTXO Ledger in Firefly?

Tags: asktheexperts

As this question comes up a lot - how does the new UTXO Ledger model work? - also in relation what is implemented in Firefly? How does the Firefly wallet keep track of the funds that belong to a profile? My understanding is this: A profile represents one seed. This seed can contain masses of different addresses with and without value. The accounts that every profile in Firefly creates are just ways of ordering those addresses internally in Firefly as it is convinient for the user. So Firefly keeps track of those accounts and the belonging addresses and balances, but ultimately they all belong to one seed.
The menoric phrase that is created in the setup process and the password i create for the wallet are the keys to unlock access to this seed.
A Stronghold backup file that is created later contains also information about the different accounts that are created internally in Firefly and so keeps track of changes that happened in the wallet after the initial setup.
Could you give some more insights how those things are sorted and organized please.